# Carpet Pad Adhesive Type Identification and Removal

Tags: hardwood-floor, adhesive, carpet, asbestos

In removing some old stair carpeting, I found this older black glue applied to hold the carpet padding in place. Does anyone have a recommendation on what type of material it is, and recommend on how to properly remove it?

I'm aware of black cut-back adhesive that some times contained asbestos. This is applied to wood in a way I have have not seen cutback adhesive applied before. Looks like it was squirted out of a caulk gun, like liquid nails, but black.

[image: Carpet Pad Adhesive]

Comment: Did you ever get it tested for asbestos ? And if yes then did it contain asbestos or no ?